# floating label not working correctly with not(:placeholder-shown)

Tags: html, css

currently I'm implementing a simple floating label. Below is a sample. The issue is, that if I fill something in the input and lose focus, the label stays at it's place and the `not(:placeholder-shown)` isn't recognized. Why?

```css
.k-textbox {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  height: 35px;
  color: #3e5569;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #e9ecef;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  font-family: "Nunito Sans", sans-serif;
}

.x-floating {
  position: relative;
}

.x-floating-label {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.x-floating > .x-floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem 0.75rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out, transform 0.1s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.x-floating > .k-textbox:focus,
.x-floating > .k-textbox:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  padding-top: 1.625rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.625rem;
}

.x-floating > .k-textbox:focus ~ span,
.x-floating > .k-textbox:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ kendo-label {
  opacity: 0.65;
  transform: scale(0.85) translateY(-0.5rem) translateX(0.15rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="x-floating">
        <input class="k-textbox" placeholder="&nbsp;"></input>
        <span  class="x-floating-label">Username</span>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `.x-floating-label` instead of `kendo-lable` in the last styles of your css.

```css
.k-textbox {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  height: 35px;
  color: #3e5569;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #e9ecef;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  font-family: "Nunito Sans", sans-serif;
}

.x-floating {
  position: relative;
}

.x-floating-label {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.x-floating > .x-floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1rem 0.75rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out, transform 0.1s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.x-floating > .k-textbox:focus,
.x-floating > .k-textbox:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  padding-top: 1.625rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.625rem;
}

.x-floating > .k-textbox:focus ~ span,
.x-floating > .k-textbox:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .x-floating-label {
  opacity: 0.65;
  transform: scale(0.85) translateY(-0.5rem) translateX(0.15rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="x-floating">
        <input class="k-textbox" placeholder="&nbsp;"></input>
        <span  class="x-floating-label">Username</span>
      </div>
```